# Remove a null character (Shell Script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I've looked everywhere and I'm out of luck.

I am trying to count the files in my current directory and all sub directories so that when I run the shell script count_files.sh it will produce a similar output to:
$

```
2 sh
4 html
1 css
2 noexts
```

(**EDIT** the above output should have each count and extension on a newline)

$ 
where noexts are either files without any period as an extension (ex: fileName ) or files with a period but no extension (ex: fileName. ).

this pipeline:

```
find * | awf -F . '{print $NF}'
```

gives me a comprehensive list of all the files, and I've figured out how to remove files without any period (ex: fileName ) using `sed '/\//d'`

MY ISSUE is that I cannot remove the files from the output of the above pipeline that are separated by a period but have NULL after the period (ex: fileName. ), as it is separated by the delimiter '.'

How can I use sed like above to remove a null character from a pipe input?

I understand this could be a quick fix, but I've been googling like a madman with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Chip

Comment: Quick fix! Thank you Cyrus

Answer (score 1):

To filter filenames that end with `.`, since filenames are the whole input line in `find`'s output, you could use

```
sed '/\.$/d'
```

Where `\.` matches a literal dot and `$` matches the end of the line.

However, I think I'd do the whole thing in awk. Since sorting does not appear to be necessary:

EDIT: Found a nicer way to do it with awk and `find`'s `-printf` action.

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | awk -F. '!/\./ || $NF == "" { ++count["noext"]; next } { ++count[$NF] } END { for(k in count) { print k " " count[k] } }'
```

Here we pass `-printf '%f\n'` to find to make it print only the file name without the preceding directory, which makes it much easier to work with for our purposes -- this way there's no need to worry about periods in directory names (such as `/etc/somethingorother.d`). The field separator is '.', the awk code is

```
!/\./ || $NF == "" {        # if the line (the filename) does not contain
                            # a period or there's nothing after the last .
  ++count["noext"]          # increment the "noext" counter
                            # note that this will be collated with files that
                            # have ".noext" as filename extension. see below.
  next                      # go to the next line
}
{                           # in all other lines
  ++count[$NF]              # increment the counter for the file extension
}
END {                       # in the very end:
  for(k in count) {         # print the counters.
    print count[k] " " k
  }
}
```

Note that this way, if there is a file "foo.noext", it will be counted among the files without a filename extension. If this is a worry, use a special counter for files without an extension -- either apart from the array or with a key that cannot be a filename extension (such as one that includes a `.` or the empty string).